# How to get https on CentOS 7 with app installed in docker

Tags: docker, centos-7, http-proxy

How to configure httpd on CentOS 7 to work as a proxy for (docker container) app running on port 8080 .
I was thinking how to make it work, my application was prepared as a docker's container (never heard about it before ;)) so first I've had to learn what is "docker" and how it works.(because the app is running in container it wouldn't let me use https).
So what I've done to achieve it:
 - Prepared VPS with httpd/apache then created a VS
 - Installed SSL Certificates on httpd.
 - Installed Docker
 - Pulled my app image
...
then to make HTTPS working I've had to reconfigure my VirtualServer as below

my VS config (updated proxy)

```
# HTTP
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.domain.co.uk
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) ht tps://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog myserver.domain.co.uk-error_log
    CustomLog myserver.domain.co.uk-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
# HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.domain.co.uk
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog myserver.domain.co.uk-error_log
    CustomLog myserver.domain.co.uk-access_log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    # Reverse proxy configuration
    <Proxy *>
        Allow from localhost
    </Proxy>    
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080

</VirtualHost>
```

...
and now it works!

Comment: Hello, yes, I already did some research and found some details. My httpd already got all the modules installed and also I created some config. Check above.

Comment: all the modules of course running. At least httpd -L said that :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the proxypass and proxypassreverse directives should not be in a location block andyour syntax needs tweeking. Try deleting the location and /location tags, and change to ProxyPass / https:.../ with corresponding proxypassreverse. (ie the syntax requires both path and url as parameters)

Comment: I don't fully understand ... would you please give an example?

Comment: After I removed < location / > I was unable to restart httpd service

Comment: Did you also insert the / in the ProxyPass and proxypassreverse lines? Also, what error did the logs show? (I'm not at my computer at, so its not practical for me to respond to your last request)

Comment: No, I did not added /, if I do it will not let me start httpd again :) but I found something else in error_log: [Fri Dec 01 16:55:22.627604 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 46095] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)

Comment: Probably, yes. What do you have to loose by trying it? The SSL warning days this setup will break very old (Windows XP era) browsers, but should not be a problem with anything more modern or safe to use on the web.

Comment: So what about this error ? What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: Or maybe I should install SSL on container first then just run it om port 443 or something ?

Comment: Problem solver, changed VS configuration, proxied it and works.